# Python HTMLParser

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I'm parsing a html document using HTMLParser and I want to print the contents between the start and end of a p tag

See my code snippet

```
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'p':
            print "TODO: print the contents"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I extended the example from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#example-html-parser-application):

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered the beginning of a %s tag" % tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered the end of a %s tag" % tag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered data %s" % data

p = MyHTMLParser()
p.feed('<p>test</p>')
```

-

```
Encountered the beginning of a p tag
Encountered data test
Encountered the end of a p tag
```

Comment: nice usage of http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#example-html-parser-application

Answer (score 7):

Based on what @tauran posted, you probably want to do something like this:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def print_p_contents(self, html):
        self.tag_stack = []
        self.feed(html)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.tag_stack.append(tag.lower())

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.tag_stack.pop()

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.tag_stack[-1] == 'p':
            print data

p = MyHTMLParser()
p.print_p_contents('<p>test</p>')
```

Now, you might want to push all `<p>` contents into a list and return that as a result or something else like that.

TIL: when working with libraries like this, you need to think in **stacks**!

Comment: you forgot to call `feed`, and lists have `append` not `push`.

Comment: on a large html file I get a `if self.tag_stack[-1] == 'p':
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, sounds like your `tag_stack` is empty?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, please check, and then edit the code here to this: `if len(self.tag_stack) and self.tag_stack[-1] == 'p':`

Comment: Remember that HTML is not XML. In particular, start and end tags need not match. For example '<ul> <li>text </ul>' (but no '</li>' necessarily). Hence the stack pop perhaps needs to continue until a match is found. But even this will not be enough for badly-formed sequences such as '<b><i>text</b></i>' (incorrect nesting).

Comment: according to the [documentation of the handle_starttag method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#HTMLParser.HTMLParser.handle_starttag) The tag argument is the name of the tag **converted to lower case** .  There is no need to call tag.lower().

Answer (score 1):

It did not seem to work for my code so I defined `tag_stack = []` outside like a sort of global variable.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
    tag_stack = []
    class MONanalyseur(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        tag_stack.append(tag.lower())
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        tag_stack.pop()
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if tag_stack[-1] == 'head':
            print(data)

parser=MONanalyseur()
parser.feed()
```