# sentence.split fetching website pages

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to create a program that fetches the html from the tv catchup website, then uses the split function to split up all the html data into just the channel name and the program that is currently on in a table, such as: BBC 1 - 'program name'. I just need help on what i do after my first split function if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE - because this is a school project i need to use the sentence.split function and i'm confused of what i would do next from this point onward if someone could point me in the right direction of what next stage of the website i need to split etc?

```
import urllib2
import string


proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "http://c99.cache.e2bn.org:8084"})

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

tvCatchup = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.TVcatchup.com')

html = tvCatchup.read()

firstSplit = html.split('<a class="enabled" href="/watch.html?c=')[1:]
for i in firstSplit:
    print i

secondSplit = html.split ('1" title="BBC One"></a></li><li class="v-type" style="color:#6d6d6d;">')[1:]

for i in secondSplit:
    print i
```

Comment: This seems to be identical to your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970053/python-fetching-webpage-data but for the update.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106249/update-a-question-or-post-a-new-question on updating a question

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use an [html parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) (see [Python HTMLParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204056/python-htmlparser) for examples) to do this. (People also often use [`regex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)). It is possible using `split` but a bit hacky... I did it anyway. The next step after initially splitting the page into large segments is to loop through them and split them into smaller segments, honing in on the information you want.

```
big_parts = html.split('href="/watch.html?c=')[1:]
for n, part in enumerate(big_parts):
    small_part = part.split('</a>')[0]
    if n % 2:       # odd numbered segments
        programme = small_part.split('"> ')[1]
        print programme
    else:           # even numbered segments
        smaller_parts = small_part.split('"')
        number = smaller_parts[0]
        channel = smaller_parts[2]
        print number, channel, ':',
```

It works because finding the text between `href="/watch.html?c=` and `</a>` happens to identify all of the segments that contain both the channel name and programme name. You can then break up these segments using identifying character sequences (`">` and `"`) to get the exact information you want. If the website changes its HTML style at all, this will probably stop working.

Comment: the only pain about this this problem is the code i currently have is flawed in the second split function so do you think i should take it off, also since i'm not at school i can't test the code in any way because of the proxy handler

Comment: You can still test the code by saving the source of that page from your browser to your desktop, then adding `tvCatchup = open('C:/myfile.html')` instead of the first part of your code that grabs the webpage. And yes your second split function doesn't do anything useful because the text in it only occurs once in the page.